# ProjectEuler 8: Is my code wrong or Is it their false?

Tags: java

I was working on [Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) and I've come up with a solution that works fine for four and five consecutive digits, giving the answers 5832 and 40824 respectively, although it seems to be failing when I try thirteen digits. The following is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int num=1;
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-13;i++){
        num=1;
        for(int j=0;j<13;j++)
            num=num*Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i+j,i+j+1));
        if(res<num)
            res=num;
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

I get "2091059712" as a result and ProjectEuler does not accept it.

What is the problem? 
Either my code is wrong or they did miscalculation.

If my code is wrong, can you help me to fix it?

Comment: It certainly looks like integer overflow.  Do you get the same result if you declare `num` and `res` as `long` instead of `int`?

Comment: Thought I jumped the gun with my guess, but turns out that overflow is a real possibility. 6^13 already is too big for an int...

Comment: @user3580294 Yes, I wondered why your guess disappeared when it's clearly the correct answer.  If you hadn't guessed before my comment, I would have posted it as an answer.  Didn't want to steal your thunder though.

Comment: You will be fine with using a long. But for future projectEuler problems you will want to look up how to use a BigInteger

Comment: For sheer joy of programming, I have created BigInteger class, using and improving it while solving Project Euler problems, including this one. :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace YES! Thank you. It is a valuable lesson for me. Question your habits.

Comment: @Keugyeol May I ask you to invent some kind of mechanism for me, to enable my car to move smoothly along the road?  I'm thinking of using a small number of rotating circular objects.  Does this sound like a good idea to you?

Comment: @David Wallace Have you not noticed my condition of reinventing wheels? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that you're getting an integer overflow. The answer is actually larger than the largest possible value of a 32-bit signed integer in Java (the `int` variable type).

Just so you know, the maximum value of the integer is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2147483647.

To fix this, just change your `num` and `res` types to `long` so that it will not overflow (overflow means that if the number is larger than the maximum value, it will overflow to the minimum value and count from there).

**Solution**:

Change

```
int num=1;
int res=0;
```

to

```
long num=1;
long res=0;
```

I can verify that you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `import java.math.BigInteger;` and use the BigInteger call to do your math. Mike is totally correct here.